# 500: Internal Server Error while Creating New User

Tags: android-management-api

I am using Google Play EMM API to create a new user but I am getting an internal server error. I have a valid Access Token that I have been creating using the same Gmail that I used while creating an enterprise. Also, I am sending all the params listed here: https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/v1/users/insert

but it's not letting me create a user.

here is my request body:

```
{
  "managementType": "emmManaged",
  "accountType": "userAccount",
  "primaryEmail": "dummy@.com",
  "accountIdentifier": "dummyIdentifire",
  "displayName": "DisplayName"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Google Play EMM API](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/getstarted) is available only to enterprise mobility management (EMM) solution providers who have completed all steps in the [registration process](https://developers.google.com/android/work/play/emm-api/register) and have been approved by Google to participate in the program.

As of now, Android Enterprise is no longer accepting new registrations for custom device policy controllers (DPC) using the Google Play EMM API. All new EMM solutions should now use the [Android Management API](https://developers.google.com/android/management/introduction), which comes with its own DPC provided by Google.

For information on how to build a public solution using the Android Management API, see [Develop your solution](https://developers.google.com/android/work/dev-options) and [Release your solution](https://developers.google.com/android/work/release-solution).